# Ubuntu VirtualBox stuck before login screen

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Alright so I've had this happen in the past, and I just ended up giving up and installing a new virtual machine. I'm new to this, so I'm hoping I've just made a simple mistake.

I have a Ubuntu machine through Oracle VM VirturalBox. My host is Windows 10.

I recently updated: `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I also installed guest additions so I could access a shared folder.

Then I clicked to reboot, and that's where my problem is--I haven't been able to successfully reboot since then.

The screen shows a bunch of [ OK  ] prompts, and it stops on one that says:

[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 120.

Although if memory serves, it stops on different prompts each time I reattempt.

EDIT: No, I guess memory doesn't serve. Seems to always stop on that prompt. The prompts before keep referencing 'gdm', like 'Removed slice User Slice of gdm'.

The solutions I've seen for similar problems use different commands. So I press CTRL + ALT + F2 to go get a terminal, but I can never login--the screen flickers so that I have to press each key a few times to get the letter to register and, since password characters never show up, I can't reliably type my password and login.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or some other solution that doesn't involve starting over from a new image?

EDIT: Solutions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638850/ubuntu-15-04-boot-hangs-on-starting-light-display-manager-after-updates) may be useful if that damn screen would stop flickering.

EDIT: After like 20 minutes, the flickering stopped and I logged into TTY2. Now having trouble attemping other solutions because my boot harddrive is full.

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is irrelevant to VirtualBox or anything else !! 
If, in Linux or other Unix, your root filesystem is full, it CANNOT work whatsoever ! 
Of course there is solution, but it does not just work.

A. How to make it now - without extra space:

1. Start you VM in [recovery mode](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZ3vzcyKbdAhVDLMAKHZckBckQFjACegQICxAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F172319%2Fhow-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode&usg=AOvVaw0J1kYv-PqTaQVNKUODIopG)  - Click in the VM fast after you restart it, to get in and press the shift. If you cannot, check with VM BIOS settings.
2. Give you root password to get a console.
3. Since you have all in one filesystem, you should be able to get to /home and delete any unnecessary files. For example, you user should have a .Trash* or a .local/share/Trash, which is your recycle bin and can be emptied.

B. Add space !
  -  9GB is quite few if you add many programs.

1. Shutdown the VM.
2. In a CMD (console in Windows) run `vboxmanage modifyhd` to increase your VM disk ([details here](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/)).
3. Start your VM from an ISO or CD (not from its disk). Or try [this solution for on-the-fly resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime) (not recommended).
4. From there, resize the Linux partition (info [here again](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/) or search for it)

Comment: Oh fantastic. Just entering recovering mode and freeing up space fixed the entire problem. Thank you very much for taking the time to help a novice out!

Comment: This should be a sticky on `google.com`